# How to make an audio tag on pause when a YouTube video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, html5-audio

I have a youtube video and a background music. So I would like to make it pause when ever the video starts playing and play it back when the video finishs. How can I do that?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PE3yw/7/)**

her is my jQuery code for audio HTML5 player:

```
var beepTwo = $("#musicBeat");
beepTwo[0].play();

$("#dan").click(function() {  
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == false) {
        $(this).addClass("is-paused");
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            // really stop the music 
            beepTwo[0].pause();
        });

     } else {
         beepTwo[0].play();  
         beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
         $(this).removeClass("is-paused");
     }

});
```

Comment: How are you embedding the YouTube video? What have you tried?

Comment: @idbehold Have a look at the demo please. Thats a simple version of my page.